# Struggling to upload a file

Tags: php

## EDIT

OK, so all I've done this morning:

I Ran this command:

```
sudo apt install php7.3-curl && \
sudo apt install php7.3-enchant && \
sudo apt install php7.3-gmp && \
sudo apt install php7.3-intl && \
sudo apt install php7.3-mbstring && \
sudo apt install php7.3-opcache && \
sudo apt install php7.3-pspell && \
sudo apt install php7.3-snmp && \
sudo apt install php7.3-sybase && \
sudo apt install php7.3-xmlrpc && \
sudo apt install php7.3-bcmath && \
sudo apt install php7.3-cli && \
sudo apt install php7.3-dba && \
sudo apt install php7.3-fpm && \
sudo apt install php7.3-imap && \
sudo apt install php7.3-json && \
sudo apt install php7.3-mysql && \
sudo apt install php7.3-pgsql && \
sudo apt install php7.3-readline && \
sudo apt install php7.3-soap && \
sudo apt install php7.3-tidy && \
sudo apt install php7.3-xsl && \
sudo apt install php7.3-bz2 && \
sudo apt install php7.3-common && \
sudo apt install php7.3-dev && \
sudo apt install php7.3-gd && \
sudo apt install php7.3-interbase && \
sudo apt install php7.3-ldap && \
sudo apt install php7.3-odbc && \
sudo apt install php7.3-phpdbg && \
sudo apt install php7.3-recode && \
sudo apt install php7.3-sqlite3 && \
sudo apt install php7.3-xml && \
sudo apt install php7.3-zip
```

Then amended my php.ini to comment out the custom set tmp_dir's I made. Then restarted my server and vollah! It now works without a hitch.

So my guess is that I was missing a module somewhere, if I had to guess, `-common` maybe? Not sure, never really looked into which module does what (probably should to avoid these issues in the future).

I'll go do some research and will make an answer once I narrow down which module fixed it.

## Edit 2

I'm fairly confident I've narrowed down the module responsible for resolving my issue. It would seem I didn't have `php7.3-curl` installed. Here is the description of the module, taken from docs:

> PHP supports libcurl, a library created by Daniel Stenberg, that allows you to connect and communicate to many different types of servers with many different types of protocols. libcurl currently supports the http, https, ftp, gopher, telnet, dict, file, and ldap protocols. libcurl also supports HTTPS certificates, HTTP POST, HTTP PUT, FTP uploading (this can also be done with PHP's ftp extension), HTTP form based upload, proxies, cookies, and user+password authentication.

Amongst that, is `file` (under the list of supported protocols).

However, uninstalling this module and restarting my webserver made no change, it still succeeded.

I'm wondering if there was some weird cache thing going on in the background that I can't figure out.

### original post

I have a function to upload an image and insert some data into the database. It's triggered by an AJAX event and it all works, until it tries to upload the image.

This is my (simplified) form HTML:

```
<form method="post"
      class="form-horizontal"
      id="add-dealers-form"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="img" id="img" />
</form>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="submit-add-model-btn">
    <span>Update Model</span>
</button>
```

The (relevant) AJAX:

```
$('#submit-add-model-btn').click(function()
{
    let form = document.getElementById('add-dealers-form'),
        formData = new FormData(form);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/app/scripts/admin/add-model.php',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(res) {console.log(res); alert(res)},
        error: function(res)
        {
            alert('Something went wrong. Please try again.');
            console.log(res)
        }
    })
})
```

The (relevant) PHP:

```
if (!$img['error']) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($tmp, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/images/models/'. $name)) {
        $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare(
            $sql,
            array($_POST['name'], $_POST['sku'], $_POST['type'], $name)
        ));
    } else {
        $response['110'] = 'There was a problem with the upload. Please try again.';
    }
} else {
    $response['110'] = 'There was a problem with the upload. Please try again.';
}
```

I've also tried with:

```
if ($img['error'] == 0)
```

I've also tried using `copy()` instead.

Adding a `print_r()` before the conditional shows that `$_FILES` and `$_POST` is populated. So no issue there.

Here's the catch (my folder permissions):

```
drwxrwxrwx  3 www-data www-data 4096 May 20 13:56 images/
```

Then models inside:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 4096 May 20 13:56 models/
```

So it has completely unsafe, wide open permissions and yet, it doesn't work. I've checked my local error logs and again, there's nothing. I've enabled error reporting within my script - still nothing.

My network tab shows that the request returns a 200 status. It also shows my error message I set up.

I've also tried removing the AJAX step and going straight to the PHP script - again, nothing.

I have gone through a few SO posts and tried alternative solutions but nothing prevailed. I'm not sure what's wrong with my script, it has the `enctype`, it has the needed ajax settings for image sending and it has full permissions, what am I missing?

File I'm trying to upload is 70kb (so can't be a size issue)

I've tested with other code that I know works (works on production server) - so it's definitely server-level. Let me know what you'd think would be useful to see (config wise) and I'll add to Q.

### Server-side settings

Potentially Useful .ini settings:

```
memory_limit = -1
upload_max_size = 2M
post_max_size = 8M
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp/php
sys_temp_dir = /tmp/php
```

Apache

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2019-04-03T13:22:37


Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php7_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

PHP

```
PHP 7.3.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: May  3 2019 10:00:24) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.5, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Permissions on `/tmp`

```
drwxrwxrwx  22 root root      12288 May 20 17:29 tmp/
```

Permissions on `/tmp/php`

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data    4096 May 20 16:28 php/
```

Answer (score -1):

This PHP/HTML code worked for me. Modify as you wish. Hope it helps: **:)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><style>
*{font-family:corbel;padding:0.8em;margin-left:2em;background:#9dc;}
</style>
<form action="files.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Files (not videos though):
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form></body></html>

<?php
$target_dir = "";
$t_f = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$stat = 1;
$f_Type = strtolower(pathinfo($t_f,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

/* Check if file already exists
if(file_exists($t_f)) {echo "Sorry, file already exists.";$stat = 0;}
*/
//Debugging
echo"<p style='color:#777'>";
print_r($_FILES["fileToUpload"]);
echo'</p>';

// Check file size. 0.5MB Max.
if($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
  echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
  $stat = 0;}

/* Allow certain file formats
if($f_Type != "jpg" && $f_Type != "png" && $f_Type != "jpeg"
&& $f_Type != "gif" ) {
  echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
  $stat = 0;}
 Check if $stat is set to 0 by an error*/
if($stat == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";}
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
else {
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $t_f)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";}
else { echo "Welcome to Aera23's uploader. This message should disappear if the file is uploaded";}}
?>

?>
```